# How can I summarize several pandas dataframe columns into a parent column name?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I've a dataframe which looks like this

```
        some feature  another feature  label
sample
0       ...           ...              ...
```

and I'd like to get a dataframe with [multiindexed](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html) columns like this

```
        features            label
sample  some       another
0       ...        ...      ...
```

From the API it's not clear to me how to use `from_arrays()`, `from_product()`, `from_tuples()` or `from_frame()` correctly. The solution shall not depend on string parsing of the feature columns (`some feature`, `another feature`). The last column for the label is the last column and it's column name `label` may be used. How can I get want I want?

Comment: `df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_',expand=True)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> From the API it's not clear to me how to use `from_arrays()`, `from_product()`, `from_tuples()` or `from_frame()` correctly.

It is mainly used, if generate new DataFrame with MultiIndex independent of original columns names.

So it means if need completely new `MultiIndex`, e.g. by lists or arrays:

```
a = ['a','a','b']
b = ['x','y','z']
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([a,b])
print (df)
        a     b
        x  y  z
sample         
0       2  3  5
1       4  5  7
```

EDIT1: If want set all columns to `MultiIndex` all columns same way without last one:

```
a = ['parent'] * (len(df.columns) - 1) + ['label']
b = df.columns[:-1].tolist() + ['val']
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([a,b])
print (df)
          parent           label
       feature a feature b   val
sample                          
0              2         3     5
1              4         5     7
```

---

It is possible by `split`, but if some column(s) without separator get `NaN`s for second level, because is not possible combinations MultiIndex and not MultiIndex columns (actaully yes, but get tuples from MultiIndex columns):

```
print (df)
        feature_a  feature_b  label
sample                             
0               2          3      5
1               4          5      7

df.columns = df.columns.str.split(expand=True)
print (df)
       feature    label
             a  b   NaN
sample                 
0            2  3     5
1            4  5     7
```

So better is convert all columns without separator to `Index/MultiIndex` first by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index('label')
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(expand=True)
print (df)
      feature   
            a  b
label           
5           2  3
7           4  5
```

For prevent original index is used `append=True` parameter:

```
df = df.set_index('label', append=True)
df.columns = df.columns.str.split(expand=True)
print (df)
             feature   
                   a  b
sample label           
0      5           2  3
1      7           4  5
```

Comment: The question was missleading. I need a solution which does not rely on string parsing.

Comment: @thinwybk - hmmm, so now not working `df.columns = df.columns.str.split(expand=True)` for split by spaces?

Comment: @thinwybk - Because MultiIndex means some pairs, triples... generated from columns names, right? If not split, what is logic here?

Comment: Splitting and reconstructing a new dataframe with hierachical column index would be ok as well.

Comment: @thinwybk - I edit answer with some sample, still not sure if understand what need.

Comment: I want to add a parent column name `feature` for all columns despite of the last one whose name is `label`. For the last column there shall be set the parent column name to `label` and the child name shall be set to ``. Exactly like in the pseudo code of the question.

Comment: @thinwybk - Problem is last columns has to be Multiindex too. All columns has to be MultiIndex

Comment: Exactly that's why I don't know how to get what I want.

Comment: @thinwybk - I think understand, give me some time

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's exaclty what I need!